# Java: Change value of a Float object

Tags: java

I have looked inside the javadoc for Float, but there does not seem to be any way to modify the value after construction?

```
Float f = new Float(1.23f);
[...]
f.setValue(3.14f); // Nothing like this seems to exist...
f = 3.14f; // "f" now points to a new object, not what I want...
```

Is there a way to change the value of the object? Alternatively, is there another wrapper class available that would allow this?

Comment: Float (like other Boxing classes) is immutable. You could try changing its value with reflection but I am not sure if that is what you want. Anyway why you want to change it? What is your real problem? Maybe there is way around.

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote: `f = 3.14f`?

Comment: If you want a mutable float wrapper (and do not need it to be derived from Float) the simplest approach is to use a one-element array of float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the value of a `Float`; all of the primitive wrapper classes are immutable. You could create your own (mutable) wrapper class if you want to add this functionality, or take a look at [`MutableFloat`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableFloat.html) from the Apache Commons.

Answer (score 4):

`Float` is a value object (immutable object).

It makes no sense to alter direclty its value without reinstantiating a new one with the new value.

Indeed, `Float` has no concept of `Identity`, it's just a pure **VALUE**, thus doesn't need a mutable behaviour.

That could be interest you, to understand the concept:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> All of the java.lang package wrapper classes are immutable: Boolean,
>   Byte, Character, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short, String.

Hence there are no setters or any other methods to change the value of the Float object.